# when and apply function (jquery) not working properly

Tags: jquery

I am looping parameter using jquery's each function. as well i am pushing all the data getting from "get" method to array. once my array is ready, i need to call a backbone function..

to do I do like this:

```
var temps = [];

        $.each(views,function(i,view){
            $.get("js/temp/" + view + ".html", function(data){
                    temps.push(data);
                    console.log(temps); //results correctly.
            })
        })

        $.when.apply(null,temps).done(function(){
            console.log(temps); //results as undefined
        });
```

but i am getting a result as 'undefined'..what is wrong here.. anyone figure out me please?

adding further question, using the answer i did..

```
$.each(views,function(i,view){
        var d = $.Deferred();
        requests.push(d.promise());
        $.get("js/temp/" + view + ".html", function(data){
                view.prototype.template = _.template(data);//not working when i use the string parameter..
                appView.prototype.template = _.template(data); //it works
                temps.push(data);
                d.resolve();
        })
    })
```

how to convert a string parameter to a return function..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need another set of deferred objects to handle this:

```
    var temps = [];
    var requests = [];

    $.each(views,function(i,view){
        var d = $.Deferred();
        requests.push(d.promise());
        $.get("js/temp/" + view + ".html", function(data){
                temps.push(data);
                console.log(temps); //results correctly.

                d.resolve();
        })
    })

    $.when.apply(null,requests).done(function(){
        console.log(temps); //results as undefined
    });
```

Using ajax deferreds:

```
    var requests = [];

    $.each(views,function(i,view){
        var d = $.get("js/temp/" + view + ".html");
        requests.push(d);
    })

    $.when.apply(null,requests).done(function(){
        console.log(arguments); //results as undefined
    });
```

Comment: actually $.get also returns deferred object, but if you need to collect data from all responses first this is an optimal way

Comment: i am getting another issue now.. actually using the parameter string, i need to get a function, and need to assign the prototype.. how to convert a string to an object..? i updated the question..

Comment: updated the answer to use ajax deferreds, now it is shorter=)

Comment: yes, thanks. works fine. as well there is an issue i am getting.. any idea? (how to get a function using string object to assign prototype)

Comment: sorry, i am not familiar with backbone

Answer (score 0):

You're only populating the `temps` array *after* the requests finish.

When you call `$.when()`, the array is still empty.

Instead, you need to create an array of promises of unfinished AJAX requests:

```
var temps = views.map(function() { 
    return $.get("js/temp/" + view + ".html"); 
});
```

Comment: but i suppose to use each method to iterate multi parameters, i idea is assigning the templates to each view of backbone.

Comment: @3gwebtrain: I have no idea what you mean.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map.  If you cannot use `map()`, you could push the promises into an array.